# NPM Module Not Found - Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, puppeteer

I can't install Puppeteer. I get the same error if I do `npm install`.

[image]

Comment: Please read [how do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) it states _"DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc -  copy or type the text into the question [instead]"_. Many of the reasons for not doing this are listed in [why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question#answer-285557). Please `edit` your question and replace the error/log images with text.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a few problems and would need to know more about your project setup to really help but here are my theories.

It would seem you do not have a package.json in that location, so npm is unable to download and build a node_modules with the puppeteer package. Try running this first:

```
npm init -y
npm install --save puppeteer
```

The -y just auto accepts a default npm setup. Then you can run:

Or if you do already have a node_modules and npm initialized, I would try:

```
rm -rf node_modules
npm install
```

Lastly, if you are looking to run this globally you should be installing this with

```
npm install -g puppeteer
```

If all of those don't work a good bet would be to reinstall Node and try again.

Also, check out the new version of puppeteer built by the same devs but at Microsoft!  [Playwright](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright)